# A set in a tensor product:

Tags: measure-theory

What "shape" do the sets of a tensor product $\sigma$-algebra come in?

Are they always product sets where each individual set in the product is measurable in its own $\sigma$-algebra? Or is this not necessarily the case?

Answer (score 0):

The tensor product of $\sigma$-algebras *generated by* the product of measurable sets. That is, it is the smallest $\sigma$ algebra that contains every such product.

As an example, consider the usual measure of $\Bbb R^2$, which is the tensor product of the usual measure on $\Bbb R$ with itself. Note that the set products themselves are all "rectangles" of some kind. Note that the set $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ is measurable, but cannot be written as such a product.